# Retrieve and then rename a file from FTP

Tags: powershell, ftp, rename, webclient

I wrote a script to retrieve a remote FTP file into a memory variable.

```
  $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
  $client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($ftp_user, $ftp_pass) 
  $file_dat = $client.DownloadString('ftp://10.10.100.10:21/data/file.dat')
```

It works, but then I need to move the original FTP file and rename it to `/data/archive/YYYY-MM-DD-file.dat` after retrieving the content.  `WebClient` doesn't look like it supports a rename.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: i don't know the details of what is returned by your FTP call, but `Rename-Item` will accept pipeline input. if your object doesn't meet any of the types that the cmdlet accepts, you can use `ForEach-Object` to wrap around the rename so that you can supply the file name as input.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey My FTP call stuffs a file's text into a variable.I don't see where Rename_Item would work with FTP unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @martin-prikryl I saw your post while doing my research, but I was hoping to rename without having to instantiate another object.  Similarly, if I use `FTPWebRequest`, I lose the `DownloadString` functionality available in `WebClient`.

Comment: If you have additional constraints, you have to say that in your question. Though `WebClient` does not support rename indeed. -- Anyway, what's the problem with *"instantiating another object"*?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No problem, just wishing one class had all the methods I needed to reduce the code overhead.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tony - i misunderstood your problem. [*blush*] i thot it was about renaming the _download_, not the _source_ file.

Comment: `FtpWebRequest` has all methods you need. It's just more low level than `WebClient` (which actually uses `[Ftp]WebRequest` under the hood).